# Nhibernate creating inaccessible path for IIS on build

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, iis, build, teamcity

I recently pushed a patch to a program Im working on to our dev and test enviornments. The tester logged on and reported this error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Mappings' is denied.
```

With this stack trace:

```
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Mappings' is denied.]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +10797222
   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) +10589262
   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost) +136
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path) +33
   DrillingContracts.DataAccess.DefaultSessionFactory.CreateSessionFactory() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\src\app\DataAccess\DefaultSessionFactory.cs:22
   NCommon.Data.NHibernate.NHSessionResolver.RegisterSessionFactoryProvider(Func`1 factoryProvider) +108
   NCommon.Data.NHibernate.NHConfiguration.WithSessionFactory(Func`1 factoryProvider) +76
   Bootstrapper.Modules.DataAccessModule.<Load>b__1(NHConfiguration c) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\Bootstrap\Modules\DataAccessModule.cs:29
   NCommon.Configuration.NCommonConfig.ConfigureData(Action`1 actions) +94
   Bootstrapper.Modules.DataAccessModule.Load(ContainerBuilder builder) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\Bootstrap\Modules\DataAccessModule.cs:24
   Autofac.Module.Configure(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry) +70
   Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules) +113
   Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options) +53
   Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.Configure() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\Bootstrap\Bootstrapper.cs:35
   DrillingContracts.IoC.WebBootstrapper.Configure() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\src\app\DrillingContracts\IoC\WebBootstrapper.cs:25
   DrillingContracts.MvcApplication.Bootstrap() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\src\app\DrillingContracts\Global.asax.cs:34
   DrillingContracts.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\5bcbb1bc83d7c1a0\Trunk\src\app\DrillingContracts\Global.asax.cs:24

[HttpException (0x80004005): Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Mappings' is denied.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9860497
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Access to the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Mappings' is denied.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874840
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

I tracked down the offending code.

```
string SchemaExportPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Mappings");

if (!Directory.Exists(SchemaExportPath))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(SchemaExportPath);
```

I tracked down the local path, and found that it is an empty directory, that seems to do nothing. This makes me incredibly nervous.

How can I diagnose how/why the production seems to care now, after multiple versions when it never mattered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah, that line of code was for the local copy only, after researching the code base more that should have been commented out.